# Get most recent record for each id

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to get a list of all users in a database. Then I have another table where I only have the users who are members.

The issue is that some of those who are members today, could have been customers, members or none of them earlier. So we could have duplicates.

What I want to do is to pick only the most recent record based on date column which is present in the database.

Here are the 2 tables output:

User table:

[Users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLIoP.png)

Members table:
[Members table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rViOl.png)

Want to left join the tables with keeping all the distinct records from users table and most matching records from members table with the most recent cd.value.

```
    WITH users AS(

SELECT
fullVisitorId AS Clientid

FROM `records`
WHERE
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY))
AND
FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
AND
totals.visits = 1


), members As(

SELECT
MAX(date) AS date,
fullVisitorId AS Clientid,
cd.value AS CD_value,
cd.index AS CD_index

FROM `records`,
UNNEST(customDimensions) AS cd
WHERE
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY))
AND
FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
AND
totals.visits = 1
AND
cd.index = 6
group by
Clientid,
CD_value,
CD_index


)

SELECT
users.ClientId AS clientId,
members.CD_value

from users


LEFT JOIN members ON users.ClientId = members.Clientid


group by
members.CD_value,
clientId


order by
clientId ASC
```

Comment: Added pictures and more description now.

Comment: Do not use pictures in questions. other developers cannot copy the contents and make your question tough to work.

Answer (score 0):

try by using row_number()

```
WITH users AS(

SELECT
fullVisitorId AS Clientid

FROM `records`
WHERE
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY))
AND
FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
AND
totals.visits = 1


), members As(

SELECT
date AS date,
fullVisitorId AS Clientid,
cd.value AS CD_value,
cd.index AS CD_index,
row_number() over(partition by Clientid,
CD_value,
CD_index order by date desc) rn

FROM `records`,
UNNEST(customDimensions) AS cd
WHERE
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY))
AND
FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
AND
totals.visits = 1
AND
cd.index = 6 


), m2 as ( select * from members where rn=1)

SELECT distinct
users.ClientId AS clientId,
m2.CD_value

from users  

LEFT JOIN m2 ON users.ClientId = m2.Clientid  


order by
clientId ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting too few rows now. Looks like I am only getting the ones which have a a cd.value. What I need is to get all clientIds and for those clientIds which have a cd.value will have it and the ones which dont will have NULL.

Comment: @user3564474 i think your user table has duplicate data

Comment: Yes. Both of the tables have duplicate data.

I need to get out the distinct values from both of them and add the latest value from members table for the clientIds which does match and NULL on the ones which does not match.

Comment: @user3564474 just add distinct in selection i have edited it on answer

Comment: Did that aswell. Still duplicates.